# Запятые при союзах И

Tags: пунктуация

В минуты музыки печальной

Я представляю желтый плес,

И голос женщины прощальный,

И шум порывистых берез...

Почему в данном отрывке ставятся 2 запятые?

Answer (score 2):

> Почему в данном отрывке ставятся 2 запятые?

В приведённом в отрывке предложении ряд однородных (*плёс, голос, шум*), соединённых союзами ***и***.

См. [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112):

> **§ 26.** Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами, если их больше двух (*и... и... и, да.., да... да, ни...
>   ни... ни, или... или... или, ли... ли... ли, ли... или... или, либо...
>   либо... либо, то... то... то, не то... не то... не то, то ли... то
>   ли... то ли*), разделяются запятыми…
>
> При отсутствии союза ***и*** перед первым из перечисляющихся членов
>   предложения соблюдается правило: если однородных членов предложения
>   больше двух и союз ***и*** повторяется хотя бы дважды, запятая
>   ставится между всеми однородными членами (в том числе и перед первым
>   ***и***):
>
> *Принесли букет чертополоха и на стол поставили, и вот передо мной **пожар, и суматоха, и огней багровых хоровод*** (Забол.)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, вопрос не возник бы, если бы союз "и" стоял пред каждым из однородных членов:

*В минуты музыки печальной я представляю И желтый плес, И голос женщины прощальный, И шум порывистых берез...*

Но даже если союз "и" не стоит перед первым из них (как в стихотворении), запятые все равно ставятся. Правило гласит:

*Если число однородных членов больше двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая ставится между ними всеми, например: А вокруг были дым, и бой, и смерть (Горбатов); Иные хозяева вырастили уже вишни, или сирень, или жасмин (Фадеев); Только мальвы, да ноготки, да крученый паныч цвели кое-где по дорогам (В. Панова*). См. [Розенталь § 87, п. 5](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xxii-znaki-prepinaniya-v-predlozheniyah-s-odnorodnymi-chlenami/ss-87-odnorodnye-chleny-soedinennye-povtoryayushchimisya-soyuzami)